# When is the exact date for Ubuntu 22.04.4 EOL?

Tags: 22.04

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases
This site currently lists Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS EOL date as April 2032

However, this site shows it as August 2024
https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle

Which one is correct?

---

@guiverc
Also, is it possible to add "HWE" vs "GA" designations to the various 22.04.x update level on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases, kind of similar to how its listed for 14.04.2->14.04.4? If that info is posted elsewhere can you please point me there?

Looking at 14.04.6 on the 1st site, I do wonder whether the process is that the last one becomes a "release" (aka GA?) and is that why its not marked as an HWE?

Lastly, is 22.04.5 going to be the last update in the 22.04.x series? I'm trying to stay with the latest-GA and wish to avoid moving to HWE. Given that constraint, is it best to stay on 22.04.1 or should I wait for 22.04.5 (since 22.04.4 is HWE)?

Comment: The release is Ubuntu 22.04; the .4 is an indication of update level (*giving clues as to kernel stack if using the HWE kernel stack*)

Answer (score 3):

**The release is Ubuntu 22.04**; with the .4 is an indication of update level (*giving clues as to kernel stack if using the HWE kernel stack*)

The HWE kernel stack has a support life of only ~6 months (*excluding GA kernel from next LTS*), and at 22.04.5 (*or actually a few weeks before 22.04.5 ISO release the kernel changes*) you'll be using the 6.8 kernel from Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

****The date you're using**** (*as I understand it*) **relates to the first field, ie. 6.5 kernel from Ubuntu 23.10**.

> 6.5   22.04.4 LTS Feb 2024    Aug 2024

**and the title showing what it relates to, ie. "*Ubuntu kernel support lifecycle*"**

**Ubuntu 22.04 LTS will continue life after August 2024**, however it'll be using the 5.15 kernel if using the GA kernel stack, or 6.8 if using HWE.

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is supported for 5 years at the *standard support* level

> Maintenance updates will be provided for 5 years from the initial
> 22.04 LTS release for Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Cloud, and Ubuntu Core. All the remaining flavours will be supported for 3 years.
> Additional security support is available with ESM (Expanded Security
> Maintenance

as [release announcements mention](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/).

April 2032 is with *standard Ubuntu support* (*where it's on-topic on sites like this*) plus **extended support** offered by Canonical.

*If you're unfamiliar with HWE kernel stack cycle changes; please refer to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack*

Comment: My language isn't clear sorry... and I've skipped reference to OEM kernel options (*they just complicate things as they are numerous*)

Comment: Looks like you're saying that the dates on those sites 22.04.x are fine, but the context is different. On the 1st site the EOL date relates to the release 22.04 in general, while on the 2nd one it relates to the kernel release cycle for a given "update level". Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is your release which has 5 years of *standard* support that can be extended via Pro/ESM to be longer, but the kernel stack life is only 6 months for non-LTS kernels (ie. 22.04 GA or 24.04 GA when it becomes the HWE kernel stack at 22.04.5 & higher).   Ubuntu Server media defaults to installing with GA kernel stack (*that doesn't change*), Ubuntu Desktop defaults to HWE kernel stack; Ubuntu *flavor* media varies with GA for 22.04 & 22.04.1 but HWE for 22.04.2 & higher. Your last comment is correct; ie. release life is not the same as kernel as stack options exist for LTS